# Webcam saving from camera without freezing application

Tags: c#, video

Hey I am trying to save a video of a webcam and save it as uncompressed. However Anytime click on the save button the application freezes until the save is complete. I will be grateful for any advice given. I am using managed code for the webcam "FLea 3" (from Points grey)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       uint k_numImages = 100;
       // ManagedAVIRecorder aviRecorder = new ManagedAVIRecorder();
       // List<ManagedImage> imageList = new List<ManagedImage>();



            List<ManagedImage> imageList = new List<ManagedImage>();
            ManagedImage rawImage = new ManagedImage(m_rawImage);
           for (int imageCnt = 0; imageCnt < k_numImages; imageCnt++)
       // while (m_grabImages == true)
            {
                m_camera.RetrieveBuffer(rawImage);
                ManagedImage tempImage = new ManagedImage(rawImage);
                imageList.Add(tempImage);

             }


            if (m_grabImages==true)
            {
           //Encoding bit
            string aviFileName;



            AviOption option = new AviOption();
            option.frameRate = 24;
            aviFileName = String.Format("SaveCSharp-aviuncompressed");
            aviRecorder.AVIOpen(aviFileName, option);
           // aviFileName = String.Format("SaveCSharp-h264");
          //  H264Option option = new H264Option();
          //  option.frameRate = 24;
          //  option.bitrate = 20000000;
          //  option.height = Convert.ToInt32(m_rawImage.rows);
           // option.width = Convert.ToInt32(m_rawImage.cols);
         //   aviRecorder.AVIOpen(aviFileName, option);

         for (int imageCnt = 0; imageCnt < imageList.Count; imageCnt++)
                {
                    aviRecorder.AVIAppend(imageList[imageCnt]);



                }
             aviRecorder.AVIClose();
            }




        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //  aviRecorder.AVIClose();
    }
    }



   }
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing any kind of operation like that on a background thread. You can use a BackgroundWorker, or you can look into System.Threading.Tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely want to run the record operation on another thread. However, that'll get slightly tricky as you have to pass messages back and forth to the recorder thread, to tell it when to stop, for example.